# How to create and use same objects in view controller methods?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.4

Hi am a experienced Java programmer.I've just stepped into learning Objective-C and XCode.I am unable to understand
a very basic but important thing which is not letting me progress any further.

I want to create objects of classes defined by me and then access and use those objects in the View Controller methods of different 
Views in the Storyboard.
I don't know where and how to create the objects so they could be accessed in any View.In Java I can do everything in main but the 
structure of Objective C is confusing me.

For example I have a class

```
@interface list : NSObject
{
NSMutableArray* ary;
}
@end
```

I want to create objects of this class and use them those objects in the methods of different View Controllers.
How can I do so?
Please can somebody just give me a to the point answer about where to create the objects so they could become accessible in View Controller methods.
I have seen far to complex answers but not basic ones
PS: I'm using XCode 4.4

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you need to either create your objects as singletons, or else keep passing a reference to the object from view controller to view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read some books or tutorials.

Some books:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-5th-Developers-Library/dp/032188728X/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1351547991&sr=1-3&keywords=stephen+kochan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032188728X)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Learn-Objective-C-Java-Developers-Series/dp/1430223693](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223693)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Objective-C-Absolute-Beginners-iPhone-Programming/dp/1430228326](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228326)

For tutorial - just google it - one of them:

- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-1/

---

Say, you have mainViewController class where you want to use your `list` class then you can do something as follows:

```
// mainViewController.h

#import "list.h"

@interface mainViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) list *objList;

@end


// mainViewController.m

@implementation mainViewController

@synthesize objList = _objList;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.objList = [[list alloc] init];
}

- (void) someMethod {
    self.objList.ary = ...;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have read some books, but please if you know someone who can explain i will be more thankful